# How can I pass Apollo data and React Router 4 url params to my components

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-v4, apollo

I’m using react router V4 and apollo client. I have a few routes that are considered private. I have these routes in their own component. I use withRouter() to wrap the PrivateRoute component so that I get all the route stuff passed down. I’m also wrapping that in a graphql query so that I know the user is logged in. My problem is that I can’t seem to get both the data from graphql and the route data.

Defining the route this way I get the apollo data, but not the match :id

`<Route exact path="/people/:id" render={() => <Person {...this.props} />} />`

And if I change the route to this, I get the params id, but no apollo data in my props

`<Route {...this.props} exact path="/people/:id" component={Person} />`

Here is my main route Component

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/create-account" component={CreateUser} />
        <PrivateRouteContainer />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Here is my PrivateRoute and PrivateRouteContainer

```
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return <Loading />;
    } else if (this.props.data.user) {
      return (
        <div>
          <VerticalNavFixed />
          <article className="docs-content">
            <Switch>
              <Route {...this.props} exact path="/people/:id" component={Person} />
            </Switch>
          </article>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />;
  }
}


const PrivateRouteContainer = graphql(userQuery, { options: { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' } })(withRouter(PrivateRoute));
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that my route already has the user pushed to it, which is all I need to make sure that the route is secure. Also, I need to wrap my other component in a different query, so I don't need the existing query data passed down to the component.  I went with this

`<Route exact path="/people/:id" render={() => <Person {...this.props} />} />`

Then in my component I wrapped it with the params variable in the options, which makes the query wait for this param.

```
export const PersonWithData = graphql(PersonQuery, {
  options: ownProps => ({ variables: { id: ownProps.match.params.id } }),
})(Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to combine the router props and the props of the query in the `React.cloneElement` function. In your case it could look like this:

```js
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return <Loading />;
    } else if (this.props.data.user) {
      return (
        <div>
          <VerticalNavFixed />
          <article className="docs-content">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/people/:id" render={(props) => {return React.cloneElement(<Person />, {user: this.props.data.user, ...props})}} />
            </Switch>
          </article>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />;
  }
}


const PrivateRouteContainer = graphql(userQuery, { options: { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' } })(withRouter(PrivateRoute));
```

Comment: Thanks, I also posted the solution I went with. I want to stay away from using React.cloneElement for now.